# mediapipe javascript to vue component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mediapipe

I'm building a project that need's to use `mediapipe` and I don't know how to implement it into my `Vue.js` project. Can you guys help me? I would love to install the `mediapie` model through `npm`, and import it at `vue component`.

This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/camera_utils/camera_utils.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/control_utils/control_utils.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/drawing_utils/drawing_utils.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/hands/hands.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <video class="input_video"></video>
    <canvas class="output_canvas" width="1280px" height="720px"></canvas>
  </div>
</body>
</html>

<script type="module">
  const videoElement = document.getElementsByClassName('input_video')[0];
  const canvasElement = document.getElementsByClassName('output_canvas')[0];
  const canvasCtx = canvasElement.getContext('2d');
  
  function onResults(results) {
    canvasCtx.save();
    canvasCtx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasElement.width, canvasElement.height);
    canvasCtx.drawImage(
        results.image, 0, 0, canvasElement.width, canvasElement.height);
    if (results.multiHandLandmarks) {
      for (const landmarks of results.multiHandLandmarks) {
        drawConnectors(canvasCtx, landmarks, HAND_CONNECTIONS,
                       {color: '#00FF00', lineWidth: 5});
        drawLandmarks(canvasCtx, landmarks, {color: '#FF0000', lineWidth: 2});
      }
    }
    canvasCtx.restore();
  }
  
  const hands = new Hands({locateFile: (file) => {
    return `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/hands/${file}`;
  }});
  hands.setOptions({
    maxNumHands: 1,
    minDetectionConfidence: 0.6,
    minTrackingConfidence: 0.5
  });
  hands.onResults(onResults);
  
  const camera = new Camera(videoElement, {
    onFrame: async () => {
      await hands.send({image: videoElement});
    },
    width: 1280,
    height: 720
  });
  camera.start();
  </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured it out, this is the code for people who facing problem using mediapipe in Vue.js

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <video ref="input_video" width="100%" height="100%"></video>
    <canvas
      class="output_canvas"
      ref="output_canvas"
      :width="width"
      :height="height"
    ></canvas>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import { Hands, HAND_CONNECTIONS } from "@mediapipe/hands";
import { Camera } from "@mediapipe/camera_utils";
import { drawConnectors, drawLandmarks } from "@mediapipe/drawing_utils";

export default {
  name: "HandModel",
  data: function() {
    return {
      number: null,
      ctx: null,
      width: null,
      height: null,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    inputVideo() {
      return this.$refs.input_video;
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.ctx = this.$refs.output_canvas.getContext("2d");
    this.init();
  },
  methods: {
    init() {
      const hands = new Hands({
        locateFile: (file) => {
          return `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/hands/${file}`;
        },
      });
      hands.setOptions({
        maxNumHands: 1,
        minDetectionConfidence: 0.5,
        minTrackingConfidence: 0.5,
      });
      hands.onResults(this.onResults);

      const camera = new Camera(this.inputVideo, {
        onFrame: async () => {
          await hands.send({ image: this.inputVideo });
        },
      });
      camera.start();
    },
    onResults(results) {
      this.width = results.image.width;
      this.height = results.image.height;
      this.ctx.save();
      this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, results.image.width, results.image.height);
      this.ctx.drawImage(
        results.image,
        0,
        0,
        results.image.width,
        results.image.height
      );
      this.findHands(results);
      this.ctx.restore();
    },
    findHands(results, draw = true) {
      if (results.multiHandLandmarks) {
        for (const landmarks of results.multiHandLandmarks) {
          drawConnectors(this.ctx, landmarks, HAND_CONNECTIONS, {
            color: "#00FF00",
            lineWidth: 5,
          });
          if (draw) {
            drawLandmarks(this.ctx, landmarks, {
              color: "#FF0000",
              lineWidth: 2,
            });
          }
        }
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.output_canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
</style>
```

Comment: can you help me setting this up on a blank Vue App